# Fetching a random row from MySQL and displaying it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to select the row quote and author from my table and echo it

my goal is to create a random quote generator and display the actual quote and author.

I have entered 25 quotes in my table with 3 rows (ID, quote, author)

my code is the following and i keep getting the resource id #9 error

```
<?php

mysql_select_db(name of database);

$quotes = "SELECT author AND quote FROM inspirational_quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($quotes);

WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
ENDWHILE; 

echo "$result";
?>
```

please help

Comment: what about "select author,quote instead of author AND quote ?

Comment: Two things. 1) ORDER BY RAND() really doesn't scale well, it's fine when it's a few hundred records, but when it's a few thousand you'll start feeling some pain from it. When it's a few million, you're finished.  Check out the book SQL Antipatterns for alternatives.  2) the mysql_* functions in PHP are deprecated in all but name. You should switch to something more modern such as PDO or Mysqli

Comment: Does the same random quote appear for each visitor that day?

Comment: no it doesnt, it will be for every new page load

Comment: Rand() should be fine since i only have 25 quotes! thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant echo $result as a string

do

```
    WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
     echo $row['author'] . " " . $row['quote'];
ENDWHILE; 


?>
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I think you want

```
<?php

mysql_select_db(name of database);
$quotes = "SELECT author,quote FROM inspirational_quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($quotes);

WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
ENDWHILE; 

echo "$result";
?>
```

but I have an additional suggestion

Preload all the quote IDs

```
CREATE TABLE quoteID
(
    ndx int not null auto_increment,
    id int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ndx)
);
INSERT INTO quoteID (id) SELECT id FROM inspirational_quotes;
```

Now choose based on the id from quoteID table

```
SELECT B.author,B.quote FROM quoteID A INNER JOIN inspirational_quotes B
USING (id) WHERE A.ndx = (SELECT CEILING(MAX(ndx) * RAND()) FROM quoteID);
```

This should scale just fine because the return value for @rnd_id comes from a list of ids with no gaps in the quoteID table.

```
<?php

mysql_select_db(name of database);
$quotes = "SELECT B.author,B.quote FROM quoteID A INNER JOIN "
. "inspirational_quotes B USING (id) "
. "WHERE A.ndx = (SELECT CEILING(MAX(ndx) * RAND()) FROM quoteID)";

$result = mysql_query($quotes);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "$result";
?>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I refined the query and the ID collection.

Answer (score 1):

You are not echoing the right variable.

```
echo $row['author'] . ": " . $row['quote'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `AND` just comma.

```
SELECT author, quote FROM inspirational_quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**[MySQL Select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to randomize results by PHP to improve performance. eg.:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM inspirational_quotes");
$d = mysql_fetch_row($r);
$rand = mt_rand(0,$d[0] - 1); 
$r = mysql_query("SELECT author,quote FROM inspirational_quotes LIMIT $rand, 1");
```